# Copying files from databricks to blob storage results in files of 0 size

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I am trying to copy a file from databricks to a location in blob storage using the below command:

```py
dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/data/conv_subset_april_2018.csv',"wasb://blobname@outputcontainername.blob.core.windows.net/" + "conv_subset_april_2018" + ".csv")
```

Now blobname and outputcontainername are correct and I have copied files earlier to the storage location. Only today when I am executing the command I am getting files of size 0. Also the file data.csv does exist in the given location and is not empty or corrupted. Does anyone have any idea what might be happening? The screenshot shows what I mean.

[Files of size 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqmwn.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

As I known, there are two ways to copy a file from Azure Databricks to Azure Blob Storage. Please refer to the offical document [`Azure Blob Storage`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) of topic `Data Sources` of Azure Databricks to know more details.

Here is my sample codes below.

1. To mount a container of Azure Blob Storage to Azure Databricks as a `dbfs` path, the you can `cp` your file in a databricks path to the mounted path of Blob Storage. Please refer to [Mount Azure Blob Storage containers with DBFS](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html#mount-azure-blob-storage-containers-with-dbfs).

   ```
   dbutils.fs.mount(
       source = "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
       mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
       extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net":"<your-storage-account-key>"})
   dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/data/conv_subset_april_2018.csv','dbfs:/mnt/<mount-name>/conv_subset_april_2018.csv')
   # Or dbutils.fs.cp('/FileStore/tables/data/conv_subset_april_2018.csv','/mnt/<mount-name>/conv_subset_april_2018.csv')
   ```
2. To set up an account access key or to set up a SAS for a container, then to copy a file from a `dbfs` file path to a `wasbs` file path.

   ```
   spark.conf.set(
       "fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
       "<your-storage-account-access-key>")
   # Or 
   # spark.conf.set(
   #     "fs.azure.sas.<your-container-name>.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
   #     "<complete-query-string-of-your-sas-for-the-container>")
   dbutils.fs.cp('/FileStore/tables/data/conv_subset_april_2018.csv','wasbs://blobname@outputcontainername.blob.core.windows.net//conv_subset_april_2018.csv')
   ```

Hope it helps.